# Paying an invoice with multiple credit cards in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a scenario where a customer may have **multiple credit cards**. The customers are charged with a **subscription fee** and **extras** that depend on the customer behavior. The customer is charged **once a month** for both the subscription fee and the extras. The extras should be paid by the credit card that is selected according to certain rules. Basically, the invoice should be split between multiple credit cards (but there is no strict requirement that there should be single invoice).

Any suggestions how can this be accomplished with Stripe?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using Stripe's built-in Subscriptions or your own logic here? I ask because Stripe's Subscriptions can only use a customer's `default_source` to pay a Subscription invoice.

Comment: @duck, I use Stripe's Subscriptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering myself because I received the answer at Stripe's IRC channel from *timebox*.

"The only way to do different cards per `Subscription` is to create a separate `Customer` object for each `Card`, and create the `Subscriptions` separately on each `Customer` object."

It isn't possible to have multiple `Subscriptions` and pay them by different cards because `Subscription` is always paid by the default card.

Having multiple `Customer` objects seems to be the only way.